# error 70, specifically for this VBA. Why is it erroring out?

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error on this line. Error 70: Permission Denied

```
wsh.Run """" & FileName & """"
```

I'm unsure what the problem is. This program is attempting to create a VB script inside to run asynchronously.

```
Private Sub CompleteUploadThread(ByVal fName As String)
Dim strScript As String, FileName As String, wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'---Create VBscript String---
strScript = "WScript.Sleep 1000" & vbCrLf & _
            "Dim wsh" & vbCrLf & _
            "Set wsh = CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")" & vbCrLf & _
            "wsh.SendKeys """ & fName & """" & vbCrLf & _
            "wsh.SendKeys ""{ENTER}""" & vbCrLf & _
            "Set wsh = Nothing"
'---Save the VBscript String to file---
FileName = wsh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("C:\Users\x7user\Desktop\Temp") & "\automation.vbs"
Open FileName For Output As #1
Print #1, strScript
Close #1
'---Execute the VBscript file asynchronously---
wsh.Run """" & FileName & """"
Set wsh
```

here's the entire code snipet

Comment: `FileName` is already a string. I don't think you have to put in in quotes

Comment: removed quotes still didn't work

Comment: Have you checked the value of `FileName` to make sure it is what you expect?

Comment: Following the suggestion by @cybernetic.nomad - the way to do this if you aren't sure is to step through the code using F8, and then when you get to the "FileName =" line, you can stop, and go into the immediate window and type: "?FileName" to see what it actually looks like when output.

Comment: yes it is correct

Comment: Is the file saved before this line is called.  Perhaps, wrap it in a loop with max retries just to be sure.  Similarly, does it work if you just try to call the script file without creating it.  So run code to create the VBS file and then just try one liner to call it?

Comment: Permission denied even having a pre-made file.

Comment: Can you run the file manually?

Comment: file can be ran manually. Once the line hits wsh.Run line. it says permission denied. Is it a naming convention thing?

Comment: I think the problem is that excel doesn't have hte correct permissions to execute the VB script?

Comment: That is not how you use the ExpandEnvironmentStrings command. Just change to "C:\Users\x7user\Desktop\Temp\automation.vbs"` for testing and it will probably work.

Comment: Remember in the future you can debug.print any variable to figure out it's value

Comment: @Trevor tried your suggestion, still has the error at line wsh.Run """" & FileName & """". Could running in admin help?

Comment: @DarkRain what is the value of FileName that is passed into the run?

Comment: @Trevor The value is the file path specified above. Does it have something to do with running from a certain location?

Comment: @DarkRain it shouldn't, permission denied usually means the file wasn't found. Unless you are running this from another user, they wouldn't have permission to x7user's desktop

Comment: @Trevor here is a picture https://imgur.com/a/9iFs50h. What was weird was this script was working before and it suddenly stopped working today.

Comment: @DarkRain don't forget to remove the extra quotes in the run command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. It was a permission issues with the folder it was in. I have to use something I have admin access to.